# Reading data from old laptop IDE harddisk with 43 + 4 pins

Tags: hard-drive

I am trying to read data from a Toshiba MK2018GAP HDD2164 H ZE01 T laptop hard disk. I have already tried to use the following device, which unfortunately does not work:

[Digitus USB 2.0 IDE/SATA Adapter Cable](https://www.digitec.ch/en/s1/product/digitus-usb-20-idesata-adapter-cable-converters-10141009?supplier=406802)

The reason may be that this device only expects 44 pins. However, the hard disk has 43 + 4 pins, as can be seen here:

[image]

So far, I haven't been able to find a device with the right number of slots. Can anyone recommend me a product to connect the disk via USB? Also, how is this IDE variation called?

Comment: Can you get the proper carrier from your local computer store? That is what I would do.

Comment: 44-pin laptop ATA is a standard. Any chance those four extra pins are for selecting master/slave/cs with a jumper?

Comment: @John what exactly do you mean with proper carrier?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann oh, that could be. But then the device I got should have worked unless the harddisk is broken. Do you agree?

Comment: You can buy AC powered carriers that hold one or more kinds of drive. It connects to a computer with a USB cable. I have a Sabrent carrier in my workshop.

Comment: @JoelRichard It should spin up. You'll hear and feel that. As for whether or not those are pins to select the mode, the manual for your adapter says it needs to be set to master. It looks like the default setting is master: https://manualsbrain.com/en/manuals/1205470/?page=4 . When you plugged it in, did you get the keying right? You didn't plug in the jumpers, did you?

Comment: It looks like the adapter doesn't have the key hole plugged, so you need to make sure you get the orientation right (their marketing material shows both the drive and the adapter face up). Ignore the four extra pins off to the right, and make sure you get all the pins in holes. It's really easy to be off by one row of pins when there's nothing ensuring proper alignment.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann it definitely did not start spinning. I have sent it back afterwards. Now I am unsure if I should just order another device and try it with this one instead or if there is just a high chance that the disk is broken.

Comment: @JoelRichard You plugged in the power do the adapter, right? 2.5" drives can usually be powered over USB, but 3.5" can't, so there's an extra power input. I wouldn't be surprised if the external power is used for the 2.5" and SATA.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann yes, I did

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a dockingstation as its eliminates power supply issues.
As of today, I see three available products available in Germany:

Freecom Hard Drive Dock Pro, USB-B 2.0
Sharkoon Quickport Combo, USB-B 3.0
StarTech UNIDOCKU33, USB-B 3.0

I have an external 2,5'' housing for IDE drives like this one
https://www.newegg.com/sanmax-hd-227-u2/p/N82E16817123105
but it did not come with an external power supply and you have to check for the right polarity of the power supply when not wanting to use USB power.

Furthermore some notebook manufacturers offer such adapters for their multi-bay. The disadvantage here is that you cannot delay the startup of the drive like with an external solution where you start up your operating system and start your IDE drive after and connect to your machine.

You could extend a modern machine with IDE by inserting a PCIe-card that provides  an IDE connector.

The cheapest one locally is from Logilink

LogiLink 2x SATA/1x IDE, PCIe x1,

others are available from Delock. I have a couple of Delock products and no reason to complain.

Check the drive manual for the position of the jumper to put it into **"master"** mode as already pointed out by David Ehrmann in the comment section!

Worst case is buying an old computer. Around 2006 mainboards appeared with both SATA and IDE connectors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't have a desktop anymore. I may give a Delock product a try.