# What kind of cable do I need to connect a Toshiba MK1237GSX hard drive to another computer?

Tags: usb, sata, hp-pavilion, toshiba-hard-drive

The connection on it seen in the picture seems different than the usual SATA connection and I can't find anything like it online. My old laptop won't turn on anymore and I was hoping to easily get a file I created after the last backup off the hard drive if possible.

[image: Toshiba MK1237GSX hard drive]

Comment: IDE. But no, those seems to be "plates"  instead of "pins". Doesn't look IDE to me.

Comment: This looks like a IDE/PATA connector and honestly I know there is some other question here asking about this exact type of connector, but I somehow cannot find it. This [image exists for another question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmyj6.png) though.  And here is another variant of that connector in [another question](https://superuser.com/q/1678724/167207).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this 48-pin laptop hard drive connector?](https://superuser.com/questions/1527997/what-is-this-48-pin-laptop-hard-drive-connector)

Comment: And now that I really looked at both, my flag as a dupe is incorrect. That question with the 48 pin connector is a SCSI drive. While this drive is a PATA/IDE drive as discussed in [this other question](https://superuser.com/q/604306/167207).

Comment: That's an adapter on top of the SATA connector. You can pull it off easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to pry away the connector shown in the image.

[image: Original photo with lines added where the original connector ends and the adapter begins]

Under (inside/behind) this connector is an SATA connector, common in the industry.

[image: hard drive ebay image]

Image from [eBay auction](https://www.ebay.com/itm/334453840959?epid=71630643&hash=item4ddf009c3f:g:6VEAAOSwCphijyi%7E&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAoG7HtD%2BcIIYv1knfoF0ljm9C8RMUwhx5OsSlQoIw5BZtxag0zMgoJaPpqPGIwVjpunVROCzcHveXhVaXB6feNQb0JdbelYNlUqcxaeI5%2B4CUN%2Bz2K71zzazwHSuaFwTG9%2BuOKFgXrwXRfxf8h5QWjzE7OBzp2rydqB%2BDgjSxzfjFdd8Qm3kOdOX5YIyDgjbDO25bnTfWhmkxq9tow2xAXFg%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR66O6_2SYQ) for reference only.

Comment: Look at the picture in the question again. It is not a SATA connector but a weird IDE/PATA connector.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I've had a situation where a cable attached to a hard drive broke and left a weird looking connector. In this case it might be he has an adaptor attached to his hard drive, converting to some weird kind of somewhat PATA/IDE looking thing. Amazon lists  his HDD as SATA. So probably his one has a weird adaptor attached that can be pulled off. It looks like it can be pulled off!

Comment: Fair enough. Will wait and see I guess.

Comment: Yep, you were absolutely right - there was an adaptor that slid right off revealing the standard SATA connector. Thank you so much to everyone who responded - you all rock!

Comment: What are the other 4 pins to the left? Do they not need to be connected?

Comment: according to a wiki entry for this type of drive, it's a non-standard set of pins commonly used by the manufacture to configure the drive or to provide features beyond the out-of-box-experience. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SATA#Cables.2C_connectors.2C_and_ports under "additional pins" about 1/3rd down the page